# Windbg _imp__xxx symbol's address seems to be dereferenced using the data segment register

Tags: debugging, assembly, linker, windbg, cpu-registers

I am learning Windbg. And for practice, I am debugging a 64bit fre app that create a process.
I added a breakpoint on CreateProcess  (bp KERNEL32!CreateProcessWStub)
When the breakpoint is hit, I disassemble the code (u) and it looks like this:

```
Breakpoint 0 hit
KERNEL32!CreateProcessWStub:
000007f9`f8024ab4 4c8bdc          mov     r11,rsp
0:000> u @rip L20
KERNEL32!CreateProcessWStub:
000007f9`f8024ab4 4c8bdc          mov     r11,rsp
000007f9`f8024ab7 4883ec58        sub     rsp,58h
000007f9`f8024abb 488b8424a8000000 mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+0A8h]
000007f9`f8024ac3 498943f0        mov     qword ptr [r11-10h],rax
000007f9`f8024ac7 488b8424a0000000 mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+0A0h]
000007f9`f8024acf 498943e8        mov     qword ptr [r11-18h],rax
000007f9`f8024ad3 488b842498000000 mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+98h]
000007f9`f8024adb 498943e0        mov     qword ptr [r11-20h],rax
000007f9`f8024adf 488b842490000000 mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp+90h]
000007f9`f8024ae7 498943d8        mov     qword ptr [r11-28h],rax
000007f9`f8024aeb 8b842488000000  mov     eax,dword ptr [rsp+88h]
000007f9`f8024af2 89442428        mov     dword ptr [rsp+28h],eax
000007f9`f8024af6 8b842480000000  mov     eax,dword ptr [rsp+80h]
000007f9`f8024afd 89442420        mov     dword ptr [rsp+20h],eax
000007f9`f8024b01 ff1591951100    call    qword ptr [KERNEL32!_imp_CreateProcessW (000007f9`f813e098)]
000007f9`f8024b07 4883c458        add     rsp,58h
```

That call to _imp_CreateProcessW is misleading because when I trace (t) to the point where I am right at that call, that's is what I see

```
KERNEL32!CreateProcessWStub+0x4d:
000007f9`f8024b01 ff1591951100    call    qword ptr [KERNEL32!_imp_CreateProcessW (000007f9`f813e098)] ds:000007f9`f813e098={KERNELBASE!CreateProcessW (000007f9`f7578960)}
```

So it looks like _imp_CreateProcessW address is a relative address (left by the linker?).
And that the data segment register (ds) is used somehow to resolve the final address (in this case, KERNELBASE!CreateProcessW (000007f9`f7578960))
This doesn't make sense though because I read that segments are not used in modern architecture (except for the fs and gs register that hold TCB's address)

My questions are:

- what's going on there?
- why is CreateProcessW not present in kernel32.dll (only the stub is). MSDN say that CreateProcess is in kernel32.dll
- what's the story behind symbols that start with *imp*. Are they linker artifacts?

Thanks!!!

Note: I run .symfix and .reload at the beginning.
The value of the registers at that moment (right before the call):

```
0:000> r
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000048 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=0000000000535138 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=000007f9f8024b01 rsp=00000000004df550 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=00000000004df5a8 r12=0000000000000000 r13=000007f7abfb1258
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000206
```

Comment: Ds is still used because the processor requires it. However it is not used in any interesting way any more. The entry point for CreateProcess is in kernel32. The fact that it calls to another DLL is an implementation detail. And "imp" symbols are references to the PE import table. But what is your partial programming question? Is there a bug that you're trying to fix?

Comment: Hi Raymond,
My question was why kernel32!_imp_CreateProcessW show up in the assembly but it's kernelbase!CreateProcessW that's called. But your comment answered it indirectly. _imp_... is the slot in the import table that contains the address of kernelbase!CreateProcessW.
Thanks!!!

Comment: If that was your question (you asked three) then it is answered here: [call stack and disassembly doubt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006468/call-stack-and-disassembly-doubt)

Comment: Interesting. In his answer, he talks about a JMP instruction. From what I saw during my debugging, _imp_... is basically the address of the slot in the import table that contains the address of the actual implementation (kernelbase!createprocessw). Not jmp are involved, call qword ptr does the trick.

Comment: See answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169172/is-createprocessw-deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

IIRC __imp_ and stubs were introduced to take care of SxS. You will notice that most if not all kernel32 & kernelbase calls end up calling __imp_.
If regards to stubs, a quick example is

```
IsDebuggerPresent()
```

Doing a **GetProcAddress** on this will return the address of **IsDebuggerPresentStub** which will jump to **IsDebuggerPresent**, which in turn will jump to:

```
_imp__IsDebuggerPresent
```

In essence, you're correct. The _imp__XXX works a bit like a VFT.

Comment: `__imp__` just represent the IAT entries and it definitely has nothing to do with SxS.