# GetStagedPackageOrigin is not found in Kernel32.dll as documented, but in Kernelbase.dll instead

Tags: winapi, dynamic-loading

I'm trying to load `GetStagedPackageOrigin` WinAPI dynamically using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress so that my app could also run on Windows 7. So [according to documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn270605(v=vs.85).aspx) that API is supposed to be imported from Kernel32.dll, but in reality (in my Windows 10 v1709) it is not.

I was able to find it in Kernelbase.dll instead:

[image]

So I'm wondering, can I dynamically load it from Kernelbase.dll instead?

Comment: You should be able to use `LoadLibrary` on `KERNEL32.DLL` regardless. There are [forwarding mechanisms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd371752(v=vs.85).aspx) in place. Did you get any errors, or are you just curious? (Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23190224/21567))

Comment: @Christian.K - it not forwarded from kernel32.dll

Comment: Why are you calling `GetProcAddress` anyway, rather than letting the system do the work for you? If you need to support versions of Windows prior to Windows 8.1, use the [Linker Support for Delay-Loaded DLLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls) to dynamically respond to availability at run time.

Comment: @IInspectable - and which dll use for `/DELAYLOAD:dllname` linker option ? and which lib file ?

Comment: @IInspectable: There are many reasons why one may not want to use delay loading of DLLs. Just to name a few: 1) It is slower & introduces unnecessary overhead, esp. when function is called often in the code. 2) It introduces unnecessary complexity, e.g. some exceptions may be raised (in a delayed load helper function) when I don't expect it 3) Delay loading calls `LoadLibrary` when I may prefer faster & more secure `GetModuleHandle` when I know that module is already loaded 4) I may want to know if API is available ahead of time (to show specific UI.) I ran out of space, but there's more to it

Comment: @c00000fd - the solution with delayload is ok, not complex or slow. but task not in this. for use delayload - need 2 things. **1:** api must be **imported** anyway. so need use some import lib library where `GetStagedPackageOrigin` is declared. so question **#1** - which import lib is use ? and **2:** - for use delayload for some dll - we must tell name of this dll to linker. we must use `/DELAYLOAD:dllname` linker option. so which **dllname** need use in `/DELAYLOAD` ??? IInspectable not give answer for this keypoint question and ignore my note.

Comment: I say that need use `/DELAYLOAD:api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll` exactly. and `OneCoreUap.lib`. but for me will be very interesting listen version of @IInspectable here. question not in use or not use delayload. but in name of dll which export this api. so from which dll need delayload. or may be IInspectable know solution how we can delayload some dll without tell linker it name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this definitely bug in documentation. if we call (test on win10)

`GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32"), "GetStagedPackageOrigin");`

we got 0 - this mean that this api not exported or forwarded from `kernel32.dll`

but if call

`GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernelbase"), "GetStagedPackageOrigin");`

we got it real address.

next - when I search in latest sdk libs - I not found `GetStagedPackageOrigin` in `kernel32.lib` too. only one lib containing this symbol - [`OneCoreUap.lib`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt654040(v=vs.85).aspx) umbrella library - and marked it exported from [`api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt654040(v=vs.85).aspx#_api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll) .this dll resolved in runtime to `kernel.appcore.dll`. implementation - simply jump to `kernelbase.GetStagedPackageOrigin`

so most correct I think try import this api from `api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll`

---

very strange appraisal for my look :) with so simply question
anybody can easy test this simply code on win8.1, win10

```
GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary(L"kernel32"), "GetStagedPackageOrigin");//fail
GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary(L"kernelbase"), "GetStagedPackageOrigin");//ok
GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary(L"kernel.appcore.dll"), "GetStagedPackageOrigin");//ok
GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary(L"api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1"), "GetStagedPackageOrigin");//ok
```

and view that by fact `GetStagedPackageOrigin` not `exported from kernel32.dll`. this is simply fact.

about lib file - i have no win8.1 sdk under hand, but i search this api in 10.x sdk version through lib files - and i found that this api implemented only in `OneCoreUap.lib` (not this symbol in kernel32.lib). and `OneCoreUap.lib` say that this api ix exported by `api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll`. so if we link with this lib - we by fact will be try import this api with `api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll` (this name will be hardcoded in our pe file).  so we need or link with `OneCoreUap.lib` (i advice add it at the end of lib list) or direct call `GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary(L"api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1"), "GetStagedPackageOrigin");`.

and can note that which header files use - absolute not related to question at all. if somebody not agree with this - can i ask - which lib need use - please **concrete** answer. and from which dll - please **concrete** dll name application will be use when use this lib (this dll name will be hardcoded in pe import table)

Comment: Surely that's the wrong solution. Surely the right solution is to use the SDK headers and libs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - what is wrong here ? `OneCoreUap.lib` this is sdk lib. *headers* - here at all not related. and which lib file need use from your view ?

Comment: It's wrong surely to attempt to load it from any specific DLL. Surely you just include the header file, link to the lib file, and that's it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - look like you wrong understand me. at first *include the header file* - here absolute unrelated at all. in heder file (*appmodel.h() only function definition. nothing say here where this function is implemented. about lib file - i and say - need use **OneCoreUap.lib** - this is only single lib file where this api is declared in latest in sdks (since 10.0.10240.0 version). if you not agree - can i ask which lib file use ? and in **OneCoreUap.lib** clear stated that this api exported from **api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll**

Comment: so once my app linked with this lib - it by fact in runtime will be use this dll. as result if ms remove `api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll` or this api from this dll - already built application which use *OneCoreUap.lib* - stop worked. so and direct call `GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary(L"api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1"), "GetStagedPackageOrigin");` will be not error

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - in any way - can i ask - which lib file need use from your view and which dll really exported this api ? and let note - after we build binary app which use specific lib - we already hardcoded dll name, from which we want import api.

Comment: @RbMm: Hey, I appreciate your analysis. I don't know why it got downvoted? People on this site are so eager to apply a cookie-cutter solution to pretty much everything. In this case it's a clear typo, or a negligence from whatever intern at MS drew a short straw to type up those MSDN docs. So yeah, it seems like the correct DLL would be `api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll`. I'm curious though, why are MS choosing such strange DLLs which are not even in the system32 folder? Wouldn't it make it less secure in a sense of DLL hijacking attack?

Comment: @c00000fd - exist simply fact - `GetStagedPackageOrigin` - not exported or forwarded from `kernel32.dll` - this is very easy can be confirmed by call `GetProcAddress`. this is both on win 8.1 and win 10. also if search by sdk libs - we can found that only `OneCoreUap.lib` actually containing this api name (I have no win8.1 sdk and not search here, but begin from 10.x version this is fact). so only one option use `OneCoreUap.lib` . the `kernel32.lib` - simply not containing this symbol. and if we use `OneCoreUap.lib` our pe will be bind to `api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll`

Comment: use delayload or not use - nothing changed here - any way `api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll` will be hardcoded in pe file. only it will be in import or delayimport structures. I really also can not understand what is "wrong" in my answer and why it downvoted. and why who is downvoted not post self, more correct and better answer - how really need call this api. which ms lib use. if use delayload - from which dll we must delayload. so simply and concrete question. why not answer ?!

Answer (score 0):

I would certainly not bind it to the versioned api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll , but the two generic ones. kernelbase or kernel.appcore.
The versions are visual studio/ucrt version specific.